# Select Multiple Different Values from Table and Evaluate them for a match in table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-like

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to select multiple records with multiple values. Let me try to break it down.

I have two tables.

Table 1: Diseases

[image]

Table 2: Symptoms

[image]

What I want to do is when the user enters a symptom, it will go through the diseases table and find the matching symptom related to it and then it will return the disease that has the symptom given.

This is the SQL query I have so far:

```
select a.diseases_id, a.disease_name
from diseases a, symtoms b 
where a.diseases_id = b.diseases_id
and b.symtom_description like '%Cough%' AND b.symtom_description like '%Sore throat%';
```

Now the problem is what this SQL query returns nothing, yet if I remove the AND statement it returns all the diseases that contain "Cough" in their symptoms, but that is not what I want. I should be able to select a bunch of symptoms and if a diseases has all the symptoms given and they match, it will return the disease. For the query that I posted, it should return "Gastroesophageal Reflux" since is the diseases that only contains Cough **and** Sore Throat.

Can anyone give me any pointers of how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no row, which contains "Cough" **AND** "Sore throat", so of course you will get an empty result.

I would try something like this (untested):

```
select a.diseases_id, a.disease_name, b.symtom_description
from diseases a, symtoms b 
where a.diseases_id = b.diseases_id
and (b.symtom_description like '%Cough%' OR b.symtom_description like '%Sore throat%')
group by a.diseases_id
having count(a.diseases_id)=2
```

Comment: You are a live saver! Works like a charm. Do you mind explaining after group by and how that made it work? And how does the having count works? What the purpose of the = 2?

Comment: HAVING is like a WHERE clause for the aggregation, so it gets applied **after** the aggregation (WHERE before).

I used the additional column _b.symtom_description_ to ensure that the aggregation gives me for each symtom one row. With _count(a.diseases_id)=2_ I request that _a.diseases_id_ needs to exist 2 times as you specified 2 symtoms in you WHERE clause. If you have 3 or something different than 2 you need to adapt this restriction of course.

Answer (score 1):

The above query could be written using the below ansi compliant join statement

```
SELECT a.diseases_id, a.disease_name, b.symptom_description
FROM diseases AS a JOIN symptoms AS b 
     ON a.diseases_id = b.diseases_id
WHERE b.symptom_description like '%Cough%' OR b.sypmtom_description like '%Sore throat%'
 GROUP BY a.diseases_id
    HAVING COUNT(a.diseases_id) = 2
```